# How to reference google maps and google maps places on the same page

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I need to use both google maps and google maps places on the same page.
The script tag for maps is

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

and the script tag for places is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Do I need to use both these calls on my page or can I just remove the  libraries=places part of the tag so that it works for both places and regular maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places"
async defer></script>
```